# Removing the class of a sibling not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working on a menu that have arrows on the buttons. On `hover` the arrow appears and the color of the button changes. Now on `click` I want to deactivate the previous active button/arrow. Now deactivating the arrow works but I cant get it to work on the button. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vDYxP/) of what Im trying to do.

Comment: You forgot the `.` in the class name I believe... it should be `siblings('.menu-btn')` as far as I can see.

Comment: I changed your css a little to see the colors better but your JS seems to be working fine to me: http://jsfiddle.net/justincook/vDYxP/1/

Comment: @Justin if you look at the colors of the buttons whitesmoke is for active and lightgrey for inactive. It still not working.

Comment: OIC, I updated my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `.` in your class name. Example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/justincook/vDYxP/2/)

change:

```
$('.right-arrow').siblings('menu-btn').removeClass('active-menu-btn');
```

to:

```
$('.right-arrow').siblings('.menu-btn').removeClass('active-menu-btn');
```

When the function is specific to classes, such as `removeClass()` the `.` isn't required. Where as when it is generic like `.siblings()` you must specifiy the `.` because it accepts all types of selectors. Such as, `#myid`, `div`, and `.myclass`